# Find an optimal matching in a complete graph

Tags: weighted-graphs, matching

I have a complete edge-weighted graph with $n$ vertices (and therefore $n\cdot(n-1)/2$ edges). I want to find a complete matching (i.e., perfect matching) in which the quotient $sum_G/A_G$ is maximal, where $sum_G$ is the sum of all the edges-weights in the matching and $A$ is the amplitude of the edges-weights in the matching. That is: If the weights of the matching's edges are $G = \{g_1, g_2,…,g_{n/2}\}$, then $sum_G = \sum_{i=1}^{n/2} g_i$ and $A = max(G)-min(G)$.

I have an algorithm that solves it using $O(n^4)$ "find a matching with maximal weight" operations:

1. For each pair of two edges (A, B) in the original graph, presume that the amplitude is in this pair, i.e. $A = weight_A – weight_B$.
2. Leave only the edges whose weights are between $weight_A$ and $weight_B$.
3. Find a complete matching with maximal weight for this sub-graph.
4. We got $O(n^4)$ matchings, we pick the best one.

The question: Is there a better way (in asymptotic notation) to find a solution?

Comment: If the subroutine for finding a maximum-weight matching can start from an existing matching, you can save a lot of time (I know that at least the Hungarian algorithm for weighted *bipartite* matching does so): Sort edges by weight; have the outer $i$-loop create a fresh graph containing just edge $e_i$; have the inner $j$-loop ($j>i$) add the next-lowest-weight edge $e_j$ to the graph with an extremely high weight to force it into an optimal matching; run "improve current matching" on this graph; adjust $e_j$'s weight back. Still $O(n^4)$ steps but each is much faster.

Comment: Also: Division by zero ($A_G=0$) when all chosen edges have the same weight?